# Migrating from MySQL to Postgres leads to performance drop

Tags: python, mysql, django, postgresql

I'm working to migrate my application from MySQL to PgSQL, because I don't like the MySQL default utf-8 3 byte char limit. Of course I could change the charset from utf8 to utf8bm4, but there are some other things I liked about PgSQL (GEO-spatial support for example). All in all I though migrating to Postgres would be the way to go forward.

However, one of the main queries is about 10x slower on Postgres then on MySQL.

This is the query explained in Postgres:
https://explain.depesz.com/s/FC5

This is the same query as with MySQL, but the MySQL variant seems to execute in +/-100ms, whereas the PgSQL variant takes about 1 second on the same tables (copied the mysql table to postgres with https://github.com/philipsoutham/py-mysql2pgsql)

Please note I'm using the Django ORM, and Django created the query for me.

Comment: Did you create any indexes?

Comment: Have you run `VACUUM ANALYZE` after running some queries? The optimizer might not have enough statistics yet to perform well. Also the DBA site might be more helpful, but do check the help section and also table definitions and query would be useful. The query does look quite complex and hard to say what it's doing without more info. Not to mention the column names...

Comment: Well, there is the (missing) DDL, there is the (missing) query, there is the (missing?) statistics, there is the (missing) configuration/tuning ...

Comment: Thanks for the comments. I didn't know about any optimizer! So I have repeated the query for 10 times and now it is performing much better. Still not on the previous (MySQL) level, but the difference has been brought back to ~200ms. I will now do VACUUM ANALYZE. Thanks!

Comment: Wow, after doing VACUUM ANALYZE it is completely back at MySQL speed! Learned again some things today, thanks!

Comment: Look at indexing also. Filter on column Five_echo removes over 200k rows. This should really be indexed for this purpose

Comment: @Mokadillion Thank you! Creating an index on Five_echo made it again a lot faster! (about 20%)